# Просмотр разметки XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin

Интересует вопрос, как во время написания `XAML`-кода в `Xamarin Forms` просматривать то, что получается, как например, это доступно в `WPF`.
Погуглил, везде пишут про `горячую перезагрузку`, но она не очень-то удобна, как минимум потому, что нужно смотреть в телефон.

Comment: Есть же эмулятор еще, но телефон конечно надежнее.

Comment: Не-не. Вы неверно поняли. мне нужен именно **предпросмотр** непосредственно в визуалке. На телефоне-то, конечно, можно, но, говорю ж, долго. Удобнее было бы как с WPF

Comment: Такого инструмента нет, либо я о подобном ничего не слышал.

Answer (score 0):

Когда готовился к WorldSkills'у так и не смог найти эту настройку. Зато сейчас нашёл.

`Средства` -> `Параметры` -> `Xamarin` -> `Xamarin.Forms предпросмотр`
в разделе `Стандартный документ просмотра` указать `Предварительный просмотр`, а расположение (2-й пункт) выбирай как тебе удобно

[Видео](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s3oj65tePL0&ab_channel=ChannelNTLTV)

[Документация Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?pivots=windows)